# Carousel with 3D rotating objects

Tags: javascript, wordpress, three.js, 3d, gsap

I trying to make something like on this site: https://sketch.london

I manage to create the objects, rotate them, give links and some motion.
I can not find how to make the carousel and show the text when hovering

This is link to what I did 
http://mstudio.co.il/spin/rotate.html
(New version)

I expect to get something similar and learn how do it, I did not found any code example I can learn from.
I still missing something?

I also want to add it to WordPress on the site homepage 
this is site: https://www.noganagarut.com/new/
I want to replace the big image with what I have done.